# python module installed and recognized, but unable to import it on my code or python 2.7.1 interpreter on Ubuntu

Tags: python, module, installation, lda

I'm stuck trying to get a python C module up and running. I'm installing deltaLDA module from [Here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~andrzeje/research/delta_lda.html). I followed the instructions as specified in REAMDE file. As usual, I wrote:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Everything went as expected I guess, I get this output:

```
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'deltaLDA' extension
    C compiler: gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC

    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7
    compile options: '-I/media/Hub/DropBox/Dropbox/Betazeta/Software/LDA/deltaLDA -I/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
    extra options: '-O3 -Wall'
    gcc: deltaLDA.c
    In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                     from deltaLDA.c:22:
    /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1155:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined
    /usr/include/features.h:214:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
    deltaLDA.c:686:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
    creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/deltaLDA.o -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/deltaLDA.so
    running install_lib
    copying build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/deltaLDA.so -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    running install_egg_info
    Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deltaLDA-0.1.1.egg-info
    Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deltaLDA-0.1.1.egg-info
```

But then when I try to import deltaLDA module I get the following error:

```
>>> from deltaLDA import deltaLDA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named deltaLDA
```

If I check for installed modules with help('modules') or pip freeze command, I'm able to find deltaLDA on both lists, but I can't import it. Please any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Updates:**
I also verified the sys.path and `'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'` it's on it. If i try to import * from deltaLDA like `from deltaLDA import *` I get the same error. On the interpreter also tried `dir(deltaLDA)` getting the same "No module name" error. Maybe there is a problem with the deltaLDA module? Someone could try to install it?

**Fixed**

I checked on the permissions of the .so and egg-info files on dist-packages. They weren't readable, I don't know why. I just ran a sudo chmod 777 file and now it's working!.

Comment: Is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` in `sys.path`?

Comment: `from deltaLDA import deltaLDA` implies that there is a module/class/method called deltaLDA within the deltaLDA module. Check the module documentation and see if that is the case. Also from a python interpreter you can do `dir(deltaLDA)` to see what all it defines.

Answer (score 1):

First try

```
>>> import deltaLDA
```

If that works review the docs or see dir(deltaLDA) as @arunkumar says, if not post your sys.path, your egg-info details please